# extjs 3 - change menuitems order in menu of a button

Tags: javascript, button, menu, menuitem, extjs3

I want to change order of the menu items of menu in a button. For example, I have a menu like following:

```
menu1
menu2
menu3
menuA
```

I add them in this order (menuA, menu3, menu2, menu1). Now i want to move menuA to  top (before menu 1) like following:

```
menuA
menu1
menu2
menu3
```

Any idea/suggestion on how to do this?

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: No one knows how to change order of the menu items?

Comment: I think you can insert(0, menuA) then remove(last)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no way to reorder the menu items so for now i just add the menu items in my required order instead of reordering them later.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing an HTA which uses extjs3 and I wanted to implement a recent files menu where if you choose a file from this menu, the chosen file should be moved to the top of the menu. I got it to work by removing all items and then adding new items in the new order

```
    ResktopDeporter.getRecentFilesMenuItems = function() {
            var a = [];
            Ext.each(ResktopDeporter.recentfiles, function(item, index) {
                a.push(new Ext.menu.Item({
                    text: item,
                    handler: function() {
                        ResktopDeporter.recentfiles.remove(this.text);
                        ResktopDeporter.recentfiles.unshift(this.text);
                        ResktopDeporter.saveRecentFiles();

                        var parent = this.parentMenu;
                        parent.hide(true);
                        parent.removeAll(true);
                        var items = ResktopDeporter.getRecentFilesMenuItems();
                        Ext.each(items, function(item, index) {
                            parent.addItem(item);    
                        });

                        ResktopDeporter.openDocument(this.text);

                    }
                }));
            });
            return a;
        }
```

`ResktopDeporter.recentfiles` is just an array of file paths and `saveRecentFiles()` writes the list to a cookie.